# Persisting changes to Windows Registry between restarts of a Windows Container

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

Given a Windows application running in a Docker Windows Container, and while running changes are made to the Windows registry by the running applications, is there a docker switch/command that allows changes to the Windows Registry to be persisted, so that when the container is restarted the changed values are retained.

As a comparison, file changes can be persisted between container restarts by exposing mount points e.g.

```
docker volume create externalstore
docker run -v externalstore:\data microsoft/windowsservercore
```

What is the equivalent feature for Windows Registry?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're after dynamic changes (each start and stop of the container contains different user keys you want to save for the next run), like a roaming profile, rather than a static set of registry settings but I'm writing for static as it's an easier and more likely answer.

It's worth noting the distinction between a *container* and an *image*.

**Images** are static templates.

**Containers** are started from images and while they can be stopped and restarted, you usually throw them entirely away after each execution with most enterprise designs such as with Kubernetes.

If you wish to run a docker container like a VM (not generally recommended), stopping and starting it, your registry settings should persist between runs.

It's possible to convert a container to an image by using the `docker commit` command. In this method, you would start the container, make the needed changes, then commit the container to an image. New containers would be started from the new image. While this is possible, it's not really recommended for the same reason that cloning a machine or upgrading an OS is not. You will get extra artifacts (files, settings, logs) that you don't really want in the image. If this is done repeatedly, it'll end up like a bad photocopy.

A better way to make a static change is to build a new image using a *dockerfile*. You'll need to read up on that (beyond the scope of this answer) but essentially you're writing a docker script that will make a change to an existing docker image and save it to a new image (done with `docker build`). The advantage of this is that it's cleaner, more repeatable, and each step of the build process is layered. Layers are advantageous for space savings. An image made with a windowsservercore base and application layer, then copied to another machine which already had a copy of the windowsservercore base, would only take up the additional space of the application layer.

If you want to repeatedly create containers and apply consistent settings to them but *without* building a new image, you could do a couple things:

- Mount a volume with a script and set the execution point of the container/image to run that script. The script could import the registry settings and then kick off whatever application you were originally using as the execution point, note that the script would need to be a continuous loop. The MS SQL Developer image is a good example, https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-docker/tree/master/windows/mssql-server-windows-developer. The script could export the settings you want. Not sure if there's an easy way to detect "shutdown" and have it run at that point, but you could easily set it to run in a loop writing continuously to the mounted volume.
- Leverage a control system such as Docker Compose or Kubernetes to handle the setting for you (not sure offhand how practical this is for registry settings)
- Have the application set the registry settings
- Open ports to the container which allow remote management of the container (not recommended for security reasons)
- Mount a volume where the registry files are located in the container (I'm not certain where these are or if this will work correctly)

**TL;DR:** You should make a new image using a dockerfile for static changes. For dynamic changes, you will probably need to use some clever scripting.